# Javascript object accessing it's properties

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to create an object in javascript that has an animation run which calls another method when it finishes.

```
function panel_manager() {
    this.animating = false;

    this.doAnimate = function (nPanel) {
        //if we're still moving panels, do nothing
        if(this.animating) return;

        this.animating = true;

        //enlarge new panel
        $("#panel" + this.focusedPanel).animate({width:"115px"},1000, this.endAnim);
    }

    this.endAnim = function () { alert("called"); this.animating = false; }
}
```

A whole lot has been cut for brevity and this code does work when it isn't inside an object and uses global variables. The alert runs, but animating isn't changing.

Comment: `$("#panel" + this.focusedPanel).animate(blah ,1000, this.endAnim);` <-- `this.endAnim` is referring to `$("#panel" + this.focusedPanel)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

variables.

```
function panel_manager() {
    var that = this;
    this.animating = false;
    this.doAnimate = function (nPanel) {
        if(this.animating) return;
        this.animating = true;
        $("#panel" + this.focusedPanel).animate({width:"115px"},1000, that.endAnim);
    }
    this.endAnim = function () { alert("called"); that.animating = false; }
}
```

Comment: Works, and I assume this is less overhead/processing to do it.

Comment: I'll point out there are more opportunities for optimization (mainly cache the 'panel' object) but I wanted the OP to see the subtle difference needed to achieve the desired results.  Proxy (or Function.prototype.bind) is more used when a function will be shared--this function only belongs to the single instance, so scoping a variable for the closure is simply correct.

Answer (score -1):

Inside of `this.doAnimate` add a $.proxy.

```
var callback = $.proxy( this.endAnim, this );

$("#panel" + this.focusedPanel).animate({width:"115px"},1000, callback);
```

Basically the problem is you lose your `this` value when you assign it to a callback like this. proxy will make sure the function is called with the proper `this`.

Cheers!

Comment: I assumed that was my problem, just couldn't find any solution to it. Thanks, it works now.

Comment: You're inside the closure, don't use $.proxy when you can just use a variable.

Comment: Please elaborate then, AutoSponge. Thanks.

Comment: sure seems like a downvote wasn't needed for a working example and an answer to the question. but yes, that works, ur a hero for sure. thanks.

Comment: sci1, it's not personal. You offered up a perfect anti-pattern which should not be emulated--using a framework method when a simple variable will do.  Beyond performance, it's just a simple understanding of how scoping works.